# Felt carbon steerer compression plug removal

Tags: carbon, headset

How do I remove a compression plug (aka. expander bung) like this one?

[image: compression plug top]
[image: compression plug side]

Most guides I could find assume that there's a 6mm hex Allen opening that allows tightening/loosening the plug (example pictured below, dark hex shape) but that's clearly not the case with mine.

[image: With hex]

I read there are designs that require screwing in the bolt partially and hitting it with a hammer until the expander's loosened but I'd rather ask first. The `→ REMOVE` and `INSTALL ←` markings seem to suggest that there's another way to remove it.

---

Note that the 2mm gap visible on second picture was caused by the plug being loose enough to be pulled up when tightening the top cap - the spacers can rotate freely and the whole fork gets slightly loose after a few days. Adding another spacer only caused the plug to slide out a bit further so I'd like to anchor the expander properly.

Comment: I think the felt is a re-brand KCNC compression plug so you could search that. Also there may be a smaller hex screw at the bottom of the threaded shaft (possibly 3mm) that may be able to be loosened. Use a bright torch to see.

Comment: Looks to me like you just twist the top plate clockwise. Have you tried that? A strap wrench or jar opener might help if it's really stuck.

Comment: I guess it *would* be possible to twist the plate but not likely without those tools. Fortunately, it turned out that there indeed *was* a hex screw at the bottom :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@DWGKNZ was right, turned out that there **was** a 3mm hex at the bottom. Picture of the removed plug, upside down:

[image: plug]

Thanks for quick and useful advice.

Comment: In my case it was a Torx key, but it was indeed hidden there and I could only find it because of this post. The instruction manual just says "Install the carbon compression plug" but doesn't specify how or with which tool. Thank you!

Comment: I have a very similar Felt plug that has a 4mm hex.

Answer (score -2):

I had to mess with one of these.  It is a horrible design so I replaced it.

It tightens by rotating the top clockwise which is impossible to do when the plug is installed.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to explain how you removed it. A short post like this that doesn't really answer the question is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: Welcome to the site - check out the Accepted answer which shows a 3mm hex socket down the middle to hold the mechanism still.  Are you saying your's was the same brand but had a different design ?